# Request for new tag: Bold for Delphi

Tags: feature-request, tag-creation, new-tags-page

I tried to add a new tag on Stack Overflow: Bold For Delphi. But it refused because I don't enough reputation. I need 1500, but only have 1283.

I think the new tag is much better description than the old [bold](/questions/tagged/bold) tag because bold is often a font issue. But Bold for Delphi is a Object Persistance framework for Delphi. Can someone with enough reputation help me?

Comment: Next time just leave a comment on the question so when someone who can create the tag comes along, they can add to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Post a question tagged 'delphi', add a link to it to your question, and someone will wander along and edit your new tag into existence.

Anyhow, [bold-for-delphi](/questions/tagged/bold-for-delphi) has been created, obvious retags done. Please consider contributing a [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/77097)!

Comment: with a smile on their face ;)